# Add numbers within list and append to new list

Tags: list, python-2.7, addition

This is what I am trying to do. Create a new list (addtwo) where the each element is the sum of the corresponding and previous elements in a source list (numberlist). Obviously the first element in new list would be same as first element in source list.

```
numberlist = [2, 4, 5, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1]
addtwo = [el[0] + el[1] for el in numberlist]
```

Produces this error message:
    TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

This is what the new list should look like, using the numbers in "numberlist":

```
[2, 6, 9, 6, 9, 10, 2, 1]
```

Comment: `for el in numberlist` iterates over *the integers* directly, how could you index into them?

Answer (score 0):

In your original attempt, el is just an integer, not a list, so trying to index it generated the error message.

You need to iterate over the contents of your original list, compute the sums, and
 then append those sums to the new list.

Something like this code:

```
numberlist = [2, 4, 5, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1]
newlist = []
newlist.append(numberlist[0])
for index in range(1,len(numberlist)): 
    sum = numberlist[index] + numberlist[index-1]
    newlist.append(sum)
print 'newlist', newlist
```

Alternative version using list comprehension, with leading element from original list is

```
numberlist = [2, 4, 5, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1]
newlist_comp = [numberlist[index] + numberlist[index-1] for index in range(1,len(numberlist))]
newlist_two = numberlist[0] + newlist_comp
print 'newlist_two', newlist_two
```